# Changing the first line in a file

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with changing a line in a file, the purpose of this code is to change the first number of the file to itself + 1. For some reason the code doesn't seem to be functioning at all, any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void changenumber(String fileName)
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    File temp = new File(fileName);
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(temp);
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            list.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String first = list.get(0);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(first);
    i = i+1;
    first = Integer.toString(i);
    list.set(0, first);
    writenumber(list,fileName);
}

public static void writenumber(ArrayList<String> list, String fileName)
{
    PrintWriter write;
    try {
        write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
        for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++)
        {
            write.append(list.get(i));
        }
        }
    catch(IOException err)
    {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try flushing the PrintWriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you never closed the `FileWriter`.

Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that file streams are closed correctly.

A few other improvements to your code:

- Do not ignore exceptions. Continuing execution as-if nothing bad happened will cause lots of problems. Let the exception bounce back to caller, and let caller decide what to do if the file cannot be updated.
- `Scanner` is slow. Since all you're doing to reading lines, use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead.
- The lines in memory don't end in newline characters, so you need to use the `println()` method when writing the lines back out, otherwise the result is a file with all the lines concatenated into a single line.
- Variables renamed to be more descriptive.

```java
public static void changenumber(String fileName) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    }
    int i = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(0));
    i++;
    lines.set(0, Integer.toString(i));
    writenumber(lines, fileName);
}

public static void writenumber(List<String> lines, String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true))) {
        for (String line : lines) {
            out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you could simplify the code immensely by using the newer [NIO.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) classes added in Java 7, in particular the [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.

```
public static void changenumber(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName);
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
    lines.set(0, Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(lines.get(0)) + 1));
    Files.write(filePath, lines);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it's working now.

Is there any advantage to using the NIO method over the first method other than simplifying the code?